# Why Does execCommand('bold') Do Nothing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg

I'm trying to make a simple WYSIWYG editor but I'm having trouble making text bold. I am able to make text underlined with `document.execCommand("underline", false, null);` and make text italic with `document.execCommand("italic", false, null);` but `document.execCommand("bold", false, null);` does nothing.

I checked the html output and it doesn't add any `<b>` or `<strong>` tags to the text either.

This is the HTML:

```
<button id="underline" type="button">Underline</button>
<button id="italic" type="button">Italic</button>
<button id="bold" type="button">Bold</button>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"></div>
```

and here is the jQuery:

```
$('#underline').click(function() {
   document.execCommand("underline", false, null);
});

$('#italic').click(function() {
   document.execCommand("italic", false, null);
});

$('#bold').click(function() {
   document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
});
```

Comment: Totally unrelated, but... Welsh Manc? How does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as far as I can tell. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/om78patL/

```
$('#underline').click(function() {
   document.execCommand("underline", false, null);
});

$('#italic').click(function() {
   document.execCommand("italic", false, null);
});

$('#bold').click(function() {
   document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
});

<button id="underline" type="button">Underline</button>
<button id="italic" type="button">Italic</button>
<button id="bold" type="button">Bold</button>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">test</div>
```

Comment: I just noticed I had some css that changed all spans in the document, but it only changed the colour not anything to do with the font-weight. Works after I took that out. Very strange.